# My 16.04 keeps locking up

Tags: 16.04

OK, it just locks up the monitor, but at one point I had audio / video going in background and it continued - so the system was not totally dead. 
Of course I couldn't not see the video, just listen to audio. 
Here is last output from /var/log/syslog

I have been collecting these logs looking for a pattern. 
I think I found one - after WARNING these few lines were on MOST of the log reports. 
So is the screen saver the culprit? Or the German "time" whatever causing this? 
Can someone tell me how to just disable any of these? 
I am not in the mood troubleshooting this to find out why it is happening, just want to try to get rid of it. 
Thanks

```
Oct 11 09:32:15 jim-desktop org.gnome.ScreenSaver[1368]: ** Message: Lost the name, shutting down.
Oct 11 09:32:15 jim-desktop ntfs-3g[2046]: Version 2015.3.14AR.1 integrated FUSE 28
Oct 11 09:32:15 jim-desktop ntfs-3g[2046]: Mounted /dev/sdb3 (Read-Write, label "Copy_Arduino_Programs", NTFS 3.1)
Oct 11 09:32:15 jim-desktop ntfs-3g[2046]: Cmdline options: rw,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,uhelper=udisks2
Oct 11 09:32:15 jim-desktop ntfs-3g[2046]: Mount options: rw,nodev,nosuid,uhelper=udisks2,allow_other,nonempty,relatime,default_permissions,fsname=/dev/sdb3,blkdev,blksize=4096
Oct 11 09:32:15 jim-desktop ntfs-3g[2046]: Global ownership and permissions enforced, configuration type 7
Oct 11 09:32:16 jim-desktop udisksd[1866]: Mounted /dev/sdb3 at /media/jim/Copy_Arduino_Programs on behalf of uid 1000
Oct 11 09:32:18 jim-desktop colord-sane: io/hpmud/pp.c 627: unable to read device-id ret=-1
Oct 11 09:32:32 jim-desktop org.gnome.zeitgeist.Engine[1368]: ** (zeitgeist-datahub:2130): WARNING **: zeitgeist-datahub.vala:229: Unable to get name "org.gnome.zeitgeist.datahub" on the bus!
Oct 11 09:32:33 jim-desktop pulseaudio[1695]: [pulseaudio] bluez5-util.c: GetManagedObjects() failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.TimedOut: Failed to activate service 'org.bluez': timed out
Oct 11 09:32:49 jim-desktop systemd[1]: Starting Stop ureadahead data collection...
Oct 11 09:32:49 jim-desktop systemd[1]: Started Stop ureadahead data collection.
Oct 11 09:32:49 jim-desktop systemd[1]: Stopped Read required files in advance.
```

Comment: Couple months ago I read the Xscreensaver author was angry at Debian because they were shipping x years old buggy version. You didn't mention what you were using though.

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me in my laptop.
I solved it by installing power management TLP

```
 sudo apt-get install tlp tlp-rdw
```